# Laravel 5.5 Entrust using middleware to grant permissions on route groups fails

Tags: exception, acl, laravel-5.5, entrust

I'm using entrust for my laravel 5.5 project to provide an ACL system. As I try to use a middleware in my routes to filter access it falls in the following case

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin', 'role:hr']],
            function () {

//other routes which should be checked by permission
});
```

if admin access routes which are inside of this method I get an exception

```
 Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ HttpException
No message
```

if I remove the second role access

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin']],
            function () {

//other routes which should be checked by permission
});
```

than it works, but I need to split this route access on permissions an can be accessed jut by this 2 roles.

What I do wrong in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't split the role checks into separate array entries.

> It is possible to use pipe symbol as OR operator:
>
> 'middleware' => ['role:admin|root']
>
> To emulate AND functionality just use multiple instances of middleware
>
> 'middleware' => ['role:owner', 'role:writer']

[Docs](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/README.md#middleware)